# How to improve this regex to not matches when the strings are in comments

Tags: javascript, regex, string, text, comments

Given this example text:

```
<input type="text" value="<? print(variable); ?>">

<? /*<br><br><small>Data:</small>

<input type="text" value="<? print(data); ?>"> */ ?>

<textarea><? print(yuppy); ?></textarea>
```

To capture all the contents (one per one) inside **<?** and **?>** I use:

`/<\?\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*\?>/g`

The issue with this regex is that it will match even the **<?** and **?>** inside the **/* */** or **//** *(comments)* and that's not the desired behavior.

How can I improve that regex to correctly match these strings when they are not in the comments?

---

To be clear, the correct matches should be:

```
1) print(variable);
2) /*<br><br><small>Data:</small>

<input type="text" value="<? print(data); ?>"> */
3) print(yuppy);
```

Instead with my regex, the second match is:

```
/*<br><br><small>Data:</small>

<input type="text" value="<? print(data);
```

---

**Update:**

The answer of Josh Crozier is almost good but is a bit buggy:

His regex `<\?\s*((?:.*\/\*[\s\S]+\*\/.*)|(?:[\s\S]+?))\s*\?>` wrongly match with https://regex101.com/r/oL5iV0/2:

```
<? /* hello */ ?>
html
<? /* world*/ ?>
```

and even with https://regex101.com/r/qW7mR7/1:

`<input type="text" value="<? print(code); ?>"> <? /* */ ?>`

In the latest example, it correctly matches only if there is a line-break. In the first example, even with line-breaks it does not correctly match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern (remove spaces and comments to make it work with javascript):

```
<\?  # opening tag
[^?\/]* # all that is not a ? or a /
(?:
    \/ # a slash:
    (?:
        (?![\/*]) [^?\/]*  # - not followed by a slash or a *
      |
        \/.*(?:\n[^?\/]*)? # - that starts a single line comment
      | 
        \*                 # - that starts a multiline comment
        [^*]* (?:\*+(?!\/)[^*]*)* # (comment content)
        (?:\*\/ [^?\/]* | $)      # */ is optional
    )
  |
  \?(?!>) [^?\/]* # a ? not followed by a >
)*
(?:\?>|$) # optional closing tag ?>
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/pS2oE2/1)

Note that this pattern can't cause a catastropic backtracking because after `<\?` all is optional, in particular the closing tag `?>` and the end of the multiline comment `*/`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an alternation, `((?:.*\/\*[\s\S]+\*\/.*)|(?:[\s\S]+?))`, to cover both cases.

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/dD5oI2/1)

```
/<\?\s*((?:.*\/\*[\s\S]+\*\/.*)|(?:[\s\S]+?))\s*\?>/g
```

It will either attempt to match everything between and around the comments (`.*\/\*[\s\S]+\*\/.*`) or it will match (`[\s\S]+?`) which is what you originally had.

Output:

```
1) print(variable);
2) /*<br><br><small>Data:</small>

<input type="text" value="<? print(data); ?>"> */
3) print(yuppy);
```

Comment: Nice, but with a text like: `<input type="text" value="<? print(code); ?>"><? /* any code */ ?>`

Your regex fails to correctly match, if there isn't a linebreak: https://regex101.com/r/qW7mR7/1 

And it fails even with two comments, even if they are on different rows
`<? /* hello */ ?> html <? /* world*/ ?>`

https://regex101.com/r/oL5iV0/2